# Highlighting a non-rectangular portion inside div on hover

Tags: html, css

I have a div ( rectangle ), and inside it I want to have a triangular shape. I want to highlight that  on hover. How do I do that?

I'm thinking of having 2 images with that same shape and different opacity and swapping them on hover. Would there be another way of doing this? can you have a non-rectangular shaped divs?

Comment: Different shapes are possible: http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Can try that:
http://jsfiddle.net/H42U7/

The css code is:

```
.triangle-up {
width: 0;
height: 0;
border-left: 50px solid transparent;
border-right: 50px solid transparent;
border-bottom: 100px solid #959595;}

.triangle-up:hover {
width: 0;
height: 0;
border-left: 50px solid transparent;
border-right: 50px solid transparent;
border-bottom: 100px solid #123456;}
```

The html:

```
<div id="container">
<div class="triangle-up">
</div></div>
```

To rotate the triangle check this site:
http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/

Answer (score 0):

It depends how far back in internet explorer you need to go and the context of your triangle as to what you are using it for, but assuming you don't care about internet explorer.

Chris Coyer over @ CSS Tricks has a nice tutorial already setup.
http://css-tricks.com/triangle-with-shadow/

If you are planning to use it as an icon or button you might want to check out, 
http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/.  Its totally free and pretty easy to implement.  I have used it in a few projects and it was made for use with bootstrap.

Hope this helps.